# BouncyCastle Exception while creating cipher

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pgp

I am trying to run a project on my tomcat locally, but I get an Exception from the BouncyCastle.

I have checked the path of the key and the keyname, all correct. I have also exchanged the jce policy files. Nevertheless the issue is still there. Any further suggestions?

Here is the entire exception:

```
org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: Exception creating cipher
        at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.open(Unknown Source)
        at com.bfs.pgp.Encrypt.encrypt(Encrypt.java:206)
        at com.bfs.pgp.Encrypt.getEncryptedString(Encrypt.java:105)
        at org.apache.jsp.webapps.xxx.pages.xxx.XXXStart_jsp.getCryptedValue(XXXStart_jsp.java:26)
        at org.apache.jsp.webapps.xxx.pages.xxx.XXXStart_jsp._jspService(XXXStart_jsp.java:158)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: cannot create cipher: No such algorithm: IDEA/OpenPGPCFB/NoPadding
        at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createCipher(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createStreamCipher(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder$MyPGPDataEncryptor.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No such algorithm: IDEA/OpenPGPCFB/NoPadding
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:673)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:580)
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.NamedJcaJceHelper.createCipher(Unknown Source)
        ... 28 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:106)
        at sun.misc.CharacterEncoder.encode(CharacterEncoder.java:188)
        at com.bfs.pgp.Encrypt.getEncryptString(Encrypt.java:237)
        at com.bfs.pgp.Encrypt.getEncryptedString(Encrypt.java:106)
        at org.apache.jsp.webapps.xxxPayment.pages.xxxx.XXXStart_jsp.getCryptedValue(XXXStart_jsp.java:26)
        at org.apache.jsp.webapps.xxxPayment.pages.xxxx.XXXStart_jsp._jspService(XXXStart_jsp.java:158)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: What version of BouncyCastle are you using? Have you tried using SpongyCastle instead?

Comment: In my pom.xml i have the following entries for BouncyCastle:
<groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
<artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
<version>140</version>
and
<groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
<artifactId>bcpg-jdk14</artifactId>
<version>1.47</version>

Comment: Is it possible that the following dependencies are in conflict with the exchange jce policy files i have mentioned above? 

<groupId>local_policy</groupId>
<artifactId>local_policy</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
and 
<groupId>US_export_policy</groupId>
<artifactId>US_export_policy</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

Comment: Considering you got a `no such algorithm` exception, my guess is that you're using an incompatible version of BC. Try another versions.

Comment: I have tried another version but the same exception still occurs.

Comment: there are many many versions and they aren't really compatible with one another >.<

Comment: IDEA is only available in the "-ext" versions of the bouncycastle provider.